# Catalan Number in using Dynamic Prog

Tags: c, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming, catalan

I was calculating the number of Binary Search Trees with n nodes, and I found out that it is  Catalan Number.

Now, using DP, here's my attempt.

```
create arr[n+1];
arr[0]=1;
arr[1]=1;
for(i=2;i<n+1;i++)
  arr[i]=0;
  for(j=1;j<i;j++)
    arr[i]+=arr[i-j]*arr[j];

//arr[n] gives the answer?
```

Is this the right way?

Can it be any better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of binary search trees over n distinct elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004723/number-of-binary-search-trees-over-n-distinct-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that your code works. Do you mean the number of unique Binary Search Trees with numbers from `1` to `n`?

For `n = 3`, the number should be `5`. But your code gave me the result `2`.

```
1         3     3      2      1
 \       /     /      / \      \
  3     2     1      1   3      2
 /     /       \                 \
2     1         2                 3
```

Here is my solution:

```
int numTrees(int n) {
    int dp[n+1];
    memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
    dp[0] = 1;
    dp[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            dp[i] += dp[j-1] * dp[i-j];
    return dp[n];
}
```

For Catalan Number, `P(3) = P(1)P(2) + P(2)P(1)`.

But in this problem, `P(3) = P(0)P(2) + P(1)P(1) + P(2)P(0)`.

So, I guess it's not Catalan Numbers.
Hope this could help you.