# What will be the complexity of this code for counting number of different BST(binary search tree)s from N nodes?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, complexity-theory, time-complexity

```
def count(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        sum = 0 
        left = 0        
        right = 0
        for x in range(1,n+1):
            left = count(x-1)
            right = count(n-x)
            sum +=  left * right
    return sum
```

I was reading this post and I wondered
if no of different binary search trees from n nodes is

`(2n)! / ((n+1)! * n!)`
 from  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042412/with-n-no-of-nodes-how-many-different-binary-and-binary-search-trees-possib)  post.

Then

1. what will be the time complexity ? O(n!) ?
2. what will be the recurrence relation ?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `count(n)`, it's calling each of `count(0)` to `count(n-1)` *twice*.

So I think you can write the recurrence like this:

`T(n) = 2 * sum[T(0) upto T(n-1)] + nk` where k represents the multiplication and summation part.

Now consider:

```
T(n+1) = 2 * sum[T(0) upto T(n)] + (n+1)k
       = 2 * sum[T(0) upto T(n-1)] + 2T(n) + nk + k
       = T(n) + 2T(n) + k
       = 3T(n) + O(1)
```

Solving this, it appears to be of `O(3^n)` complexity.

Comment: If you're pointing to the growth of the Catalan number, that doesn't mean anything. The growth of the function itself and how you compute the values are two different matters.