# Number of binary search trees possible with nodes equal to or less than n

Tags: algorithm

I know total number of distinct BST's possible with N distinct nodes are given by **Catalan formula** .
Which is described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042412/with-n-no-of-nodes-how-many-different-binary-and-binary-search-trees-possib) at SO.

But how can we use it to find all the BSTs less then or equal to n nodes(N distinct nodes)?

for e.g.

For N=3

```
 Possible numbers of BST's are 14.

 9 Shown in Picture below for less than 3.
 5 for N=3 which can be obtained from Catalan formula.
```

[image: BST FOR N 3]

What is the approach to solve it?  **I need only algorithmic explanation**.

Comment: that will not be correct. `catalanFormula(1)=1,catalanFormula(2)=2,catalanFormula(3)=5` sum of which gives 8 for 3. But answer is 14.

Comment: Its a live contest answers. why are u in such hurry for answers. Answers are anyway published after contests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mathematical formula shall be:

```
summation ( C(n,i) * Catalan(i) ) {i = 1 to n}

Where C(n,i) = n! / ( i! * (n-i)! )
```

You can choose `i` nodes out of a possible `n` nodes in `C(n,i)` ways. After choosing those `i` nodes, form the BSTs in `Catalan(i)` number of ways.

Comment: Yes, but you should note that the number increases atleast exponentially (possibly at a factorial rate).