# TreeToList in Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I have this function that i wrote to pass from a tree to a list in Haskell:

```
treeToList :: Tree -> [Int]
treeToList (Leaf x) = [x]
treeToList (Node left x right) =  treeToList left ++ [x] ++ treeToList right
```

This works just fine, however i have a doubt:

With the input:

```
treeToList (Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 3) 4 (Leaf 5)))
```

the function produces this list:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

which, i think is wrong, because if i want to go the other way around, and write the tree from the list, i'm going to write it wrong.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: It's not obvious what you mean by "write wrong". There are many ways we can turn a list into a tree (while keeping elements in order). Also, if you want to "go the other way", you'll have to write an entirely different function, so I don't  see why this `treeToList` is relevant to that.

Comment: It is not possible to go the other way around: any tree visit (pre-, post-,in-) defines a non-injective map from trees to lists, so information is lost. At bast, you can achieve a pseudo-inverse, i.e. reconstructing one of the many trees which once visited give the input list back.

Comment: @AndrásKovács so this is a correct way of transforming a tree into a list ?

Comment: @laker001 Yes. This is an [in order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29) of a tree. It is perfectly valid.

Comment: For a given _n_ you have many possible shapes of an _n_-element binary tree, but just one list. So there is no way how to go back without additional information. See [With ' N ' no of nodes, how many different Binary and Binary Search Trees possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3042412/1333025).

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct way to transform a binary tree of `Int` into a list by "in-order" traversal. This is the most common way to turn a search tree into a list. There are, however, other valid ways to traverse trees which will produce lists in different orders for various purposes, as you can see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). As András Kovács and chi have indicated, there is generally no way to go backwards, unless you have specific information about the shape of the tree you wish to construct.