# what is the solution of this recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, recurrence

if *T(n)* is the number of different binary search trees on *n* distinct elements then

[image: The recurrence relation]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/aa6fa60.gif))</sub>

what is the value for *x* please explain.

Comment: @Sneftel its about recurrence relation used to find the time complexity of the algorithms so why its off topic please explain

Comment: I don't know why would someone bring back the question form four years ago, but just in case anyone bothers, the answer was given seven years ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/12531995/4687565

Answer (score 1):

*Any* element can be the *root* of the tree. The rest of the elements will go in the left or right sub-tree depending on whether they are smaller or larger than that element.

Those sub-trees are also binary search trees, so based on this you can write a recurrence relation.

The rest is left as an execercise, as this is clearly homework.

Comment: Karoly Horvath its not a homework problem it is a question that  came in a competitive exam in India since i could not find the solution any where i asked it here